# Formatting of braces for C++ in Visual Studio Code

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code, c, lint, braces

I've [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) of Microsoft as my default formatter. When I save/run my code the opening curly braces automatically move to newline instead of staying in sameline. How can I prevent this? (It doesn't happen after I disable the extension.)

[image]

In settings, I found an option *position of opening braces for blocks* that I set to sameline, but the braces keep moving to newline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606364/14313852

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension is by default using [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) formatter, which has this behavior of placing curly braces.

You can disable it with `C_Cpp.formatting` setting and then setup your own formatting rules.

You could also change the rules of ClangFormat with `C_Cpp.clang_format_style` setting or within `.clang-format` file. Read more about configuration [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#configuring-style-with-clang-format). Especially about [BreakBeforeBraces](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#breakbeforebraces).

Comment: Thanks :) I searched for `C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle` in Settings and changed it to `{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4 }`. Now my braces are in sameLine.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the text editor settings? there is a setting for format on save. it was off by default for me, but maybe something happened with your vscode. try turning that off if it is on.

Comment: That's not quite a solution to disable all the formatting to avoid one problem.